# Método .click de Jquery no funciona correctamente

Tags: html, jquery, css

Estoy creando un menú, que al darle un botón, aparezca un desplegable (Que cambie el ancho inicial a un ancho más grande), pero cuando lo hago, aparece y desaparece, no se mantiene.

¿Cómo hago para que una vez que se haga clic el menú quede totalmente desplegado?

Aquí mi código:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#menu").click(function(){
         $("#elemIzq").removeClass('plegado').addClass("desplegado");
            });
});
```

```css
#elemIzq {
position: absolute;
float: left;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
background-color: rgb(84, 102, 131);
border-right: 3px solid #091d3e;
}
.plegado{
width: 54px;
}
.desplegado{
width: 300px;
}

#menu{
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 50%); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav id="elemIzq" class="plegado">
   <ul>
     <li><a href=""><span id="menu" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

EDITADO:

Al parecer si aplico el `click` al padre, a `#elemIZq`, si funciona, pero yo quiero que se haga `click` en el `span`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es que se regrese el estado, lo que hace es que se actualiza la página ya que en su `<a href="">` no tiene nada y cuando se da `click` al `span` se dispara el evento `click` del `<a>` ya que es hija. lo más común seria  añadir `#` al tag `a` y evitar la recarga. además esto  de añadir y remover clases , se puede lograr con [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#elemIzq").toggleClass('desplegado');
    });
});
```

```css
#elemIzq {
position: absolute;
float: left;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

display: inline-block;
background-color: rgb(84, 102, 131);
border-right: 3px solid #091d3e;
}
.plegado{
 width: 54px;
}
.desplegado{
 width: 300px;
}

#menu{
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 50%); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav id="elemIzq" class="plegado">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span id="menu" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Madre mía que despiste, muchas gracias...